# Include and Exclude in the same AWS DMS Selection Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapping, cloud, aws-dms

Look at this rule:
`{       "rule-type": "selection",       "rule-id": "8",       "rule-action": "exclude",       "object-locator": {         "table-name": "%_temp%",         "schema-name": "plf"       },       "rule-name": "8"     }`

Now I want to edit this rule in such a way that it only takes the table xyz_temp but excludes all others with "%_temp%" in it.

In order to create another rule for doing it, we need to create a new DMS task. Therefore I wanted to see if there is any possibility of achieving this in a single rule.

I asked ChatGPT the same question and this was the response that I got:
`{   "rule-type": "selection",   "rule-id": "8",   "rule-action": "include",   "rule-name": "8",   "object-locator": {     "schema-name": "plf"   },   "exclude-object-pattern": "%_temp%",   "include-objects": [     {       "schema-name": "plf",       "table-name": "xyz_temp"     }   ] }`

Not sure if that would work because I did not find anything like exclude-object-pattern in the docs!

Comment: What is your requirement? Do you only need to get the data from a single table i.e. table_temp?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate data only from table xyz_temp, you just specify only that table in the selection rule. DMS task migrates data only from whichever table mentioned in the mapping rule. You don’t need to have a exclude rule if you want to migrate only from xyz_temp, when you specify the table name in the mapping rule.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).